# Building a lib with the same symbols as another lib

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries

I want to build a shared lib for an embedded system which has to substitute another lib. I have tried simply to build a lib with the same symbols. When I compare the original lib with mylib there is a slight difference. Hence the executable cannot find this symbol in my fake lib.

Fake lib:

```
0000000000000c90 g    DF .text  0000000000000098  Base        dbus_pending_call_unref(DBusPendingCall*)
```

Original lib:

```
0000000000020430 g    DF .text  0000000000000070  Base        dbus_pending_call_unref
```

As you can see the parameter of the function is not visible in the original lib. Could be this the reason why the executable cannot find the symbol? How can I make the parameter in the symbol invisible for my fake lib?

I used objdump -TC to see the symbols and within my src-file I have used the CMake export header to export the symbol.

Comment: Presumably you're trying to do this without recompiling the original library that uses the shared lib, so you're getting an ldd error or similar when you try and run the binary with the fake lib in place. What exactly is the error that you get?

Comment: It knows the argument type.  Suggests that you used C++ and forgot `extern "C"`.

Comment: The error I get is: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libtest.so: undefined symbol: dbus_pending_call_unref

Comment: The problem was the missing `extern "C"`. Now it finds the symbol :-)

Answer (score 0):

You already pointed that the solution was adding `extern "C"`, but for context, here's the answer:

C++ allows functions to be overloaded depending on the input parameters, so for instance the following two functions can be defined separately:

```
void foo(char *bar);
void foo(const char *bar);
```

For this to work, you need to make sure these symbols are different, so the symbol name is "mangled", to encode the parameters as part of the symbol name. On modern Linux (and most other modern Unices) the convention for this mangling is the [Itanium convention](https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling) which starts with `_Z`. The `c++filt` software can be used to encode/decode these mangled symbols to something human readable.

C, instead, do not support overloading of functions, so the sole function name (and not its parameters) is part of the symbol name.